# How to get the file location of rasters registered with the PostGIS extension?

Tags: postgis, raster, raster2pgsql

Using `raster2pgsql` I am able to load a NetCDF file into PostgreSQL using the PostGIS 3.1 extension. And looking at the documentation I can see that it's possible to register a raster file instead of copying the data to PostGIS using the `--register` flag (https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html):

```
-R, --register
Register the raster as a filesystem (out-db) raster.

Only the metadata of the raster and path location to the raster is stored in the database (not the pixels).
```

Then I see that there is a 40KB table in PostgreSQL that corresponds to the raster file. How can I get the file location of this raster using SQL? Surely since Postgres links to the file I can find out where the file is stored on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Bands are stored separately. You can get the path of a band with [ST_BandPath](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_BandPath.html).